# "Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state" exception while hosting application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, crystal-reports, stack-overflow

I have a application that uses some crystal report templates to generate reports. For one of the report, when I run the report on localhost, debugging from visual studio it works fine without any issue. When the same app is hosted in IIS and I try to run the same report from the website address as mentioned in IIS, the report fails and throws an exception "Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state."

I am using Visual studio 2010 and IIS 7.5. Please share some thoughts.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research on the issue, I came to learn that the issue is with the available memory in IIS for the execution of method. when we debug in Visual Studio it provides more memory and thus the exception doesn't occur. But when the same code is deployed to IIS it fails as IIS fails to provide that much memory.

Refer this for more:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d1ba7e1-e68c-4327-ba81-0df1041ea0d2/unmanaged-dll-working-on-development-server-but-throws-stackoverflowexception-on-iis-7?forum=iewebdevelopment

Also, in my case I solved the error by refactoring the method into smallest possible sub methods so that a big method is not loaded into memory at once.